# Does this make sense .. to you ? word choice help .. please

Tags: word-choice

I'm trying to define some variable definitions for a report I am drawing up, but I need a second opinion & some help rewriting it to become a bit more formal..

Background, it's call center where an agent calls to get a customers account balance and arrange with an agent (using system dial) , then transfer to agent , then if they talked and agreed they make arrangement.

here we go:

Call Volume = Number of dial calls

Apps Volume = Number of unique applications ( same day )

Transferred Calls = Number of calls that dialer transferred  to agents ( with agent ID )

Contacted Calls = Number of calls that agents  directly talked to  customers

Arranged Calls  = Number of successfully arranged calls that occurred same day ( including customer call back after outbound dial , or system leave a message)

Contact Arranged Calls  = Number of successfully arranged calls that occurred same day ( contacted calls only )

Arranged Amount = Arranged amount for all successfully arranged calls

Contact Arranged Amount = Arranged amount for contacted arranged calls

===> I have problem with word choices and I like some opinion or recommendation how can I change this definitions to become more formal. My boss said I can't use same word as the variable in my definition, he didn't understand what I meant by these. Does this make sense to you? I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear, Consider using the [English Language Learners site](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) next time,I have attempted to correct some of the errors but at some points I could not tell what you were trying to say

Here goes

Call Volume = Number of dialed calls

Apps Volume = Number of unique applications per day

Transferred Calls = Number of calls that dialer transferred to agents ( with agent ID )

Contacted Calls = Number of calls that agents directly talked to customers

Arranged Calls = Number of successfully arranged calls that occurred same day ( including customer call back after outbound dial , or system message left)

Contact Arranged Calls = Daily successfully arranged calls counter( contacted calls only )

Arranged Amount = Arranged amount for all successfully arranged calls

Contact Arranged Amount = Total Amount of calls that have been tried